# How to use DataProcessors with TYPO3 plugins

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase, typo3-9.x

The way to add a DataProcessor to a PAGE or a FLUIDTEMPLATE is often shown. How can it be assigned to a TYPO3 plugin?

For a PAGE you can do it like this:

```
page {
    10 {
        dataProcessing {
            1558428437 = BK2K\BootstrapPackage\DataProcessing\ConstantsProcessor
            1558428437 {
                as = myconstants
                key = settings.constants
            }
        }
   }
}
```

But can you do something like this:

```
config.tx_extbase {
    dataProcessing {
        1558428437 = BK2K\BootstrapPackage\DataProcessing\ConstantsProcessor
        1558428437 {
            as = myconstants
            key = settings.constants
        }
    }
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible since data processors is a feature of the [`FLUIDTEMPLATE` content object](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html#dataprocessing) alone.

In this case you can invoke the `ConstantsProcessor` manually in your controller action. You can get the current `ContentObjectRenderer` via `$this->configurationManager->getContentObject()`. The `$processorConfiguration` is the same as in TypoScript but as array:

```
$constantsProcessor = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConstantsProcessor::class);
$data = $constantsProcessor->process(
    $this->configurationManager->getContentObject(),
    [],
    [
        'key' => 'settings.constants',
        'as' => 'myconstants',
    ],
    []
);

// Use $data['myconstants']
```

Comment: The configuration looks wrong to me, for some reason you always have to add the "dataProcessing." => [] level within your configuration array.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. There is no need for such nesting since the processor directly uses the given "key" and "as". See https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/blob/11.0.2/Classes/DataProcessing/ConstantsProcessor.php#L46

Comment: My fault, I tend to use the ContentDataProcessor.php which needs the extra level. Which is of course not true when directly using the processors.

Answer (score 3):

That's currently not possible.

This would definitely be a feature that would make live of Integrators much easier.

Comment: I'm not aware of any existing issue, proof of concept or anything else. Some extensions like EXT:news try to circumvent that with custom signals to allow modification of variables.